# Adding Text into Center of Pie Graph highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am after adding text into the center of a pie chart its to have a certain font, font-size and font-color. How is that possible to do for the code below using highcharts?

I have tried quite a few ways to resolve this using other posts but there is nothing that seems to answer this question fully and that actually works.

Here is the code I have:

```
$(function() {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#26d248', '#323232']
});

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
            renderTo: 'summoner-pie-container',
            type: 'pie',
             backgroundColor:'transparent'

        }, plotOptions: {

        series: {
            marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        pie: {
            borderWidth: 0
        } 
    },


      title: {
text: '',
style: {
    display: 'none'
}
}, credits: {
  enabled: false
}, exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        }    
    }
   },
  tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [["Damage Dealt",34000],["Team Damage Dealt",86423]],
            size: '60px',
            innerSize: '70%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use renderer to draw custom elements on top of a chart:
`http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer`

You can use css method on svg element to change its style:
`http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element.css`

Example:

```
// Render chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart(options);

// Create custom text element
var text = chart.renderer.text('100%').add(),
    textBBox = text.getBBox(),
    x = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth * 0.5) - (textBBox.width * 0.5),
    y = chart.plotTop + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5) + (textBBox.height * 0.25);
// Set position and styles
text.attr({ x: x, y: y }).css({ fontSize: '13px', color: '#666666' }).add();
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/zLhwqnq2/

Answer (score 0):

All of your answers seem to be answered within the HighCharts documentation. See for example, the following page: [HighCharts Documentation on Style](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style).

Remember that styles are accessed in Javascript in camel case (background-color becomes backgroundColor for example), so font-family becomes fontFamily.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
chart: {
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'helvetica'
    }
} });
```